# Soundblaster gives only fizzing sound

Tags: sound, sound-blaster

Since Windows 7 utterly failed to recognise my built-in audio card, I figured I'd just buy a SoundBlaster. At first everything was fine, it worked perfectly in both Windows and Linux. However, now, when I boot Kubuntu, computer doesn't produce any legible sound. Whenever there should be any sound (like on system start or with some notifications), speakers just fizz at the top of their voice. It works fine in Windows, so it shouldn't be a hardware problem. What can be wrong?

I'm running Kubuntu 10.10. Also maybe I should mention that I bought and installed SoundBlaster after installing Kubuntu.

Comment: Which SoundBlaster card did you buy?

Comment: Could you try ubuntu from livecd? maybe it's a problem with Phonon, and we could see if it works with pulseaudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the simple things first. Have you tried reconfiguring audio in Kubuntu? That might just resolve the issue right there. If you changed your hardware, you might just have to simply reset the configuration in Kubuntu (don't use Kubuntu, but it may be that simple).

Know that when you switch a piece of hardware, it can alter the system and if the system starts up with the older settings, then this may account for the "fizzing" sound.

Try resetting the hardware configuration for sound and see how that works. Might resolve this quickly and easily. Sound Blasters are not unknown, unless it is some  Windows-only model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How does one reset sound configuration? Without it it just a comment - not an answer.